# Is it different to access from ip than localhost?

Tags: ip, apache-http-server

I installed Apache web server in a computer. Since I'm the only one who needs to access it for now, i added the line `Listen 127.0.0.1:80` so that only I can access it.

Before this I could access the site by typing the ip that was in `ip addr`. After this, i was only able to get in by typing `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`. Is it intended to happen this way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it intended to happen this way?

Yes.

Before changing the `Listen` setting, Apache was listening on every interface: the one from `ip addr` and the loopback (`localhost` and `127.0.0.0/8` are the same). This can bring issues, as other hosts on your network could access Apache on port 80 by using your internal IP.

Now you changed the setting, so Apache will only listen to `127.0.0.1`. That's a good move, because now it's not trivial to access your server from other machines without exploiting a vulnerability somewhere.